# Inheritance in Java and how are members inherited

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns

I was looking into the builder design pattern and ran into a bug. Why is the Person member from PersonBuilder class different in DetailsBuilder and JobBuilder classes? Shouldn't they be the same object and the org and name functions update the same object?

When I run the code I get the following output:

```
Person{name='name', org='null'}
Person{name='name', org='null'}
Person{name='null', org='org'}
Person{name='null', org='org'}
```

Code:

```
class Person
{
    public String name;
    public String org;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", org='" + org + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}

class PersonBuilder {
    Person person = new Person();

    public DetailsBuilder details() {
        System.out.println(person);
        return new DetailsBuilder();
    }
    public JobBuilder job() {
        System.out.println(person);
        return new JobBuilder();
    }
    public Person build(){
        return person;
    }
}

class DetailsBuilder extends PersonBuilder{

    public PersonBuilder name(String name) {
        this.person.name = name;
        System.out.println(person);
        return this;
    }
}

class JobBuilder extends PersonBuilder{


    public PersonBuilder org(String org) {
        this.person.org = org;
        System.out.println(person);
        return this;
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PersonBuilder personBuilder = new PersonBuilder();
        Person p = personBuilder.details().name("name").job().org("org").build();
        System.out.println(p);

    }
}
```

Comment: I am bit not sure, what is the question. Can you provide source code, which does not work as you expect? PS: for simple builders you can use project lombok. See https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because each time you're creating a builder you're creating an own instance of Person of it. So You'll get a different instance of Person each time you create of those builders. If you need the same instance then you must need to pass the previous reference of Person object.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new JobBuilder or DetailsBuilder within PersonBuilder you're also creating a new instance of the Person object

```
public class TestJavaCode {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PersonBuilder personBuilder = new PersonBuilder();
        System.out.println("personBuilder.person: " + personBuilder.person.hashCode());
        DetailsBuilder details = personBuilder.details();
        System.out.println("details.person: " + details.person.hashCode());
        PersonBuilder name = details.name("name");
        System.out.println("name.person: " + name.person.hashCode());
        JobBuilder job = name.job();
        System.out.println("job.person: " + job.person.hashCode());
        PersonBuilder org = job.org("org");
        System.out.println("org.person: " + org.person.hashCode());
        Person p = org.build();
        System.out.println("p: " + p.hashCode());
        System.out.println(p);

    }
}
```